# $3\times3$ matrix inverse and multiplication

Tags: matrices

[image: The question]

[image: My answer]

[image: Textbook answer]

Which answer is correct? Mine or this from the textbook?

Comment: There is an easy way to check -- compute $AB$ and you should get the diagonal matrix with diagonal $1,1,-1$

Comment: I think textbook is wrong. You are correct.

Comment: gt6989b - you mean compute BA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1%2F10%2C%203%2F10%2C%207%2F10%7D%2C%20%7B3%2F10%2C%201%2F10%2C%20-1%2F10%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F5%2C%20-3%2F5%2C%20-2%2F5%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C%203%2C%20-1%7D%2C%20%7B-1%2C%201%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7B2%2C%200%2C%20-1%7D%7D) that your answer multiplied by $B$ gives the correct matrix. The textbook is wrong.

Comment: thanks, I probably wouldn't have known how to do that on wolframalpha otherwise.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Check it by hand. These aren’t very big matrices.

Comment: Yeah so what? With this question, I was also checking I hadn't given the incorrect matrix for AB to begin with. And just because I can compute these by myself doesn't mean it's not useful to know I *could* use wolframalpha for bigger matrices or more complicated matrix multiplication